# Why does _WINDLL preprocessor definition affect compatibility with 64-bit DLL registration

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, 64-bit

This question is an extension to my last [question](https://superuser.com/questions/573432/32-bit-dll-registers-on-install-win7-64-bit-but-not-regsvr32).

After doing a Beyond Compare with other projects that create .DLL's, I was able to figure out how to build my .DLL--by removing the _WINDLL preprocessor definition in the VC++ 6 project--so that would register on a 64-bit machine. I'm looking for an explanation why this happens.

In Visual Studio, once I go to the Project Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor definitions, and delete _WINDLL, then build the project, I can then register the .DLL on Windows 64-bit machines. If the defintion is included, I get the "This module failed to load" error when trying to register on a 64-bit machine.

So, can someone tell me what is going on that causes this issue? I have looked around here but nothing led me to a conclusion. Lastly, my .DLL seems to work properly, but can I safely say my application won't be affected by excluding the define?

Comment: Might have to do with calling conventions; 64-bit Windows is more standardized on a 64-bit-specific convention, which is an extension of fastcall IIRC.  Using a different calling convention may well cause Windows headaches.

Comment: @cHao It's built with MSVC6, so it's 32 bit code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Then it makes no sense to me either.  :P

Comment: BTW... VC6?  Seriously?  *Why*, when there have been 6 versions since then that don't suck nearly as bad (and almost all have free versions)...?

Comment: Can't really help it when you're the new guy.